How to modify LimPID?
Problem:

The LimPID from the Modelica Standard Library with its connected input blocks (RealExpression for u_s, u_m) is too cumbersome

It is not possible to invert the signal easily, but the inputs u_s and u_m need to be connected inversely


Solution requirements:

I would like to create an extension of LimPID, where I can use the interface of the LimPID block to directly enter the variables for u_s and u_m. Thereby, I do not need any real blocks in my diagram anymore

I would like to add a boolean parameter "invertSignal" that easily inverts the signal.


My first attempt to solve this problem was to create an extension of LimPID. Within that extension, I would put the RealExpression blocks and create conditional connections, which would be inverted if the invertSignal is set to true.
However, I get the error These connectors both create the signal, which makes sense. Additionally, I would need to hide the connectors on the outside, because the signal is already coming from the inside. However, I do not know how to make a model instance protected, that was declared as public in the base model.
The second option would be to create a duplicate of LimPID and its base class SVcontrol, but I'd rather not do that in order to avoid redundancies and to miss updates to the source classes.
Option 3 could be to create a new class, that contains two RealExpressions, the LimPID and an RealOutput. In order to parametrize the LimPID, one would have to either enter the a sub-GUI or I would have to create every parameter again and pass it on to the LimPID instance. In the latter case, there would be the update issue again.
Is there any smarter way of handling this issue?

I think you listed pretty much all possibility that Modelica offers. The only thing to add is that you can use the relatively new break statement to remove parts that are inherited from a base-class. To do so (assuming you have a recent version of Dymola), you can extend the LimPID, select the blocks you want to remove in the graphical layer and delete them. This will add something like break u_s in the modification of the extends statement for removing the set-point input. This way you can redefine its definition. Not the best way in my personal opinion, but a possibility...

Thank you Markus, maybe I will go with that!

If you want to invert any (simple causal) model the usual approach is to use Modelica.Blocks.Math.InverseBlockConstraints as seen in Modelica.Blocks.Examples.InverseModel, and not write your own model.
That would be possible to adapt to PID or LimPID:
model InverseModel 
  "Demonstrates the construction of an inverse model"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;

  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.LimPID PID(
    k=1,
    Ti=0.3,
    yMax=5,
    initType=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Init.InitialState)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{22,22},{2,42}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine sine(
    f=2,
    offset=1,
    startTime=0.2)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,20},{-60,40}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.InverseBlockConstraints inverseBlockConstraints
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,20},{30,40}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Feedback feedback
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,0},{-60,-20}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.CriticalDamping criticalDamping(n=1, f=50*sine.f)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-40,20},{-20,40}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp ramp(duration=2, startTime=4)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-12,72},{8,92}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.LimPID PID1(
    k=1,
    Ti=0.3,
    yMax=5,
    initType=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Init.InitialState)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{18,-24},{-2,-4}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k=0)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-38,-68},{-18,-48}})));
equation 
  connect(PID.y, inverseBlockConstraints.u2)
    annotation (Line(points={{1,32},{2,30},{-6,30}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(sine.y, criticalDamping.u) annotation (Line(
      points={{-59,30},{-42,30}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(criticalDamping.y, inverseBlockConstraints.u1) annotation (Line(
      points={{-19,30},{-12,30}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(sine.y, feedback.u2) annotation (Line(
      points={{-59,30},{-50,30},{-50,-2}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(ramp.y, PID.u_m) annotation (Line(points={{9,82},{12,82},{12,46},{-6,46},
          {-6,12},{12,12},{12,20}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(inverseBlockConstraints.y2, PID.u_s)
    annotation (Line(points={{27,30},{24,30},{24,32}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(feedback.u1, PID1.y) annotation (Line(points={{-42,-10},{-8,-10},{-8,-14},
          {-3,-14}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(PID1.u_s, inverseBlockConstraints.y1) annotation (Line(points={{20,-14},
          {38,-14},{38,30},{31,30}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(const.y, PID1.u_m)
    annotation (Line(points={{-17,-58},{8,-58},{8,-26}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (
         experiment(StopTime=10),
    uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end InverseModel;

However, that is only for one of the inputs, but you could do something similar for the other one. A worse problem is that LimPID cannot be inverted in the limits.

I think there was a misunderstanding. here The question about "inverting" the signals was rather related to toggle the "interpretation" of the controller inputs. Namely switch u_s := u_m and u_m := u_s, not inverting the causality of the overall block.

Oh, that would be handled by having an optional toggle-block before them.

Yes, that was a misunderstanding, anyhow, thank you very much for the effort you put in this! =)
